# Getting Object Object while doing GET (pokemon API)

Tags: javascript, angular, get

Hello I'm kinda new to this things and I'm doing a get from pokemon API, this is the [API URL](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/) I'm using.

This is my code **:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Pokemon, Pokemon2 } from 'src/app/classes/pokemon';
import { PokemonService } from 'src/app/services/pokemon.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  pokemon:any[] = []
  constructor(private pokemonservice: PokemonService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.pokemonservice.getPokemon().subscribe((data:any)=>{
     this.pokemon= data
     console.log(this.pokemon)
   })
  }
}
```

I have a service who return only the http
the problem is that in my page it says `OBJECT OBJECT`, I know data is like this **:**

```
"count": 1126,
"next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20&limit=20",
"previous": null,
"results": [
{
"name": "bulbasaur",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
}
```

I usually had data's with only an object but here says also `COUNT`, `NEXT`, `PREVIOUS`, How can I do with this ?

Comment: somewhere you're coercing an object to be string .... the object you're looking for is then `results` property of the object you receive

Comment: I've put onInit : this.pokemon= data.results 
then in the html i did test with {{pokemon | json}} and i see the json. Problem is if i put {{pokemon}} i get object object and if i do {{pokemon.name}} or {{pokemon.results}} i see nothing on screen. Probably im doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

There is no pokemon.name and pokemon.results is [object object] (Array of objects to be accurate).

Try this:
{{ pokemon.results[0].name }}. It will give you the name of first pokemon. If you would like to list all pokemon names you can do this:

```
<div *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemon.results">
  {{ pokemon.name }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Im kinda new and trying to improve and this community really helps.
I will try to do also other crud operations, i think will be hard but i try, thanks again!